# Can I use a retry policy in an azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'm using event hubs to temporary store data which will first be saved to azure table storage and then indexed to elasticsearch.
I was thinking that I should do the storage saving calls in an azure function, and do the same for the elasticsearch indexing using NEST.
It is important that the data is processed, so I was thinking that I'll use Polly as a retry policy in case the elasticsearch server is failing. However, won't a retry policy potentially make the azure function expensive?
Is azure functions even the right way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Polly for retries inside your Azure Functions. Some further considerations:

- Yes, you will pay for the retry time. But given that your Elastic Search is "mostly up", the extra price for occasional retries should not be too high.
- If you want to retry saving to Table Storage too, you will have to write calls decorated with Polly yourself instead of otherwise preferred output binding
- Make sure to check if order of writes is important to you and whether you should retry Table Storage writes to completion before you start writing to Elastic, or vice versa. Otherwise you can do them in parallel with `async` and then `Task.WaitAll`
- The maximum execution time of a Function is 5 minutes by default, you can configure it up to 10 minutes max. If you need to handle outages longer than that, you probably need a plan B. E.g. start copying the events that are failing for longer than 4 (or 9) minutes to a dedicated Queue, and retry from there. Or disabling the Function for such periods of downtime.

Comment: I want to retry saving to table storage as well. Does it make sense to use two seperate event hubs and handle indexing in one and table storage saving in the other? For instance, as soon as the data has been successfully saved to table storage the object will be passed on to the indexer event hub.

Comment: If you don't have a requirement for those two writes to happen strictly in order one after the other, you could have two consumer group for the *same* event hub: one consumer writing to Table Storage, one to Elastic. That means two Azure Functions, one per consumer group.

Comment: They do not necessarily have to happen in a strict order. A possible scenario is that storage fails and indexing does not. The data will then be out of sync. However, perhaps I am overthinking this - if the storage error is handled correctly, it will get saved eventually. Perhaps the best option will be to use two consumer groups, and a dedicated queue for failed events. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You could use a library or better just write a simple linear backoff strategy —
 like try 5 times with 5 seconds sleep in between — and do something like

```js
context.log.error({
    message: `Transient failure. This is Retry number ${retryCount}.`,
    errorCode: errorCodeFromCallingElasticSearch,
    errorDetails: moreContextMaybeSomeStack
});
```

every time you hit the retry logic so it goes to App Insights (make sure you [integrate with App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring), else you have no ops or it's completely dark ops).

You can then query for how often is it really a miss and get an idea on how well things go at the 95% percentile.

Occasionally running 10 seconds over the normal 1 second execution time for your function is going to cost extra, but probably nowhere near a full dedicated App Service Plan. If it comes close, just switch to that, it means your function is mostly on rather than off - which is still a perfectly good case for running a function.

[App Insights can also trigger alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-alerts) if some metric goes haywire, like your retry count goes up to 11 for 24 hours, you probably want to know about that deviation. You'll need to send the retry count as a custom metric to trigger an alert off of it:

```js
context.log.metric("CallElasticSearchRetryCount", retryCount);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm considering using a separate app for handling the event processing, especially since it might take longer than 10 minutes. I can use my existing app service plan in which I', hosting my web app. In terms of pricing, will there be a big difference?

Comment: Just remember you can still use a function on a dedicated plan. There is no execution time limit in that case.